# 'entity is deleted' error when deploying to packaging org

Tags: trigger, managed-package, deployment, delete-managed-package

**Exposition:**
I have a managed package and I'm trying to apply my recent dev work to the main packaging org. This work includes implementing a new architecture for all my triggers, so I needed to add about 45 new triggers to the package, completely replacing the 30 or so old ones.

**Problem:**
For some reason, whenever I attempt to deploy my triggers to the org, they all receive the error `entity is deleted` (or in some cases `Trigger name is already in use` instead). This is utter nonsense however, since none of these triggers has ever existed in this org before and all of them use a new naming convention which makes them all very different from the pre-existing ones.

**Notes:**
Interestingly, I can get successful deployment on most of the triggers if I save them to the server *one at a time* (which is just as painful as it sounds) but about a dozen of them still refuse to deploy, throwing one of the two errors above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my issue. It turns out that when you delete anything from your managed package, its name and component type get perpetually stored in a blacklist (viewable in the `Deleted Components` section of the packaging UI) which prevents you from **ever** creating another component of the same type using that name.
So it turned out that several of my triggers were in fact reusing names of triggers that had been removed from the package several years ago...

The solution was to simply rename the offending triggers, but unfortunately I had to save every single trigger to the server *individually* to determine which ones were using duped names.

Answer (score 0):

If you are "cloning" change sets, SF will keep a copy of the components added at that time (almost like versioning.

Example: You cloned "MyChangeSet1" which had a trigger named "myTrigger", but you had renamed/deleted that trigger.   SF doesn't have the latest version of "myTrigger", so you'll need to re-add it to the change set to ensure it has the latest version of the trigger.

Comment: No change sets here, I'm deploying directly into the packaging org (just as I have hundreds of times in the past)